# Burniate mobile-calendar.app tag

Tags: support, tags

I accidentally created this tag instead of [mobile-calendar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-calendar) to be inline with other tags like [mobile-safari](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-safari).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done - As long as no one uses it before the next tag culling interval (0000 UTC I believe) we should be set.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to involve a moderator to delete a tag like this. If you accidently create a tag, simply remove the tag from the questions that it is used on (likely one if you created it) and at 3:00 UTC it will be deleted automatically.